# Removing a node from a linked list by specifying one parameter of the objects stored

Tags: java, list

I hope my question doesn't bore you. I have been tasked to create a menu and a voting system, I am trying to dynamically add candidates onto a linked list, with the name and the party of the candidate being the only parameters. In the menu I have the option to delete a candidate if the user wishes to do so, so he is prompted to enter the name of the candidate, supposedly unique, and then the node containing that object should be removed. This what I have so far:

```
 package votingEntities;
    import java.util.*;
    public class CandidateMakerMenu 
    {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int menuChoice = 0;
        //int numOfCandidates = 0;
        int candidates = 0;
        String nameOfCandidate;
        String partyOfCandidate;
        LinkedList candidateList = new LinkedList();
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please Choose an Option:\n");
            System.out.println("\t1. Add Candidate\n"
                                + "\t2. List Candidates\n"
                                + "\t3. Delete Candidate\n"
                                + "\t4. Vote\n"
                                + "\t5. Results\n"
                                + "\t6. New Election\n"
                                + "\t7. Exit\n");
            menuChoice = EasyIn.getInt();
            switch (menuChoice)
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("\nName of candidate "+(candidates+1)+" : ");
                nameOfCandidate = EasyIn.getString();
                if(candidateList.indexOf(nameOfCandidate) != -1)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nCandidate name has to be unique, please choose different name\n");
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("\nParty of candidate "+(candidates+1)+" : ");
                partyOfCandidate = EasyIn.getString();
                Candidate c = new Candidate(nameOfCandidate,partyOfCandidate);
                candidateList.add(c);
                candidates++;
                System.out.println("\nNumber of Candidates: "+candidates);
                break;
            case 2:
                if(candidates < 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nNo candidates in list yet\n");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(candidateList);
                break;
            case 3:
                if(candidates < 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nNo candidates to delete\n");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("\nEnter name of candidate to delete: ");
                nameOfCandidate = EasyIn.getString();
                int candidateIndex =candidateList.indexOf(nameOfCandidate);
                if(candidateIndex == -1)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nCandidate can not be found in list\n");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    candidateList.remove(candidateIndex);
                    candidates--;
                }
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                candidateList.clear();
                break;
            case 7:
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("\nChoice must be a value between 1 and 6.\n");

            }           
        }
        while(menuChoice != 7);

    }
```

So my issue is with case 3, I don't understand why is it not removing the object. I'm new to implementing linked lists, so I understand it might be something silly but I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: It looks like your list contains `Candidate` objects, but you are trying to pass a `String` into `indexOf`. So `indexOf` will always return `-1` because a `Candidate` is not equal to a `String`. You probably need to actually loop through the candidates to find the one with the matching name.

Comment: Thank you @khelwood I will try to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it make sense, you could define equality on Candidate class to return true if name is same :

```
class Candidate {
    String name; // or whatever is is really is your class
    String party; // same as abover
    ...
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (! (other instanceof Candidate)) {
            return false;
        }
        return name.equals(((Candidate) other).name);
    }
    public int hash() {
        return name.hash();
    }
}
```

That way, you can successfully use `indexOf` on the list of `Candidate` to find  `nameOfCandidate` :

```
Candidate c = new Candidate(nameOfCandidate, "anyPartyName");
int candidateIndex =candidateList.indexOf(c);
```

Comment: I think I understand your method, and I appreciate your time. Surely though there must be a simpler way of just iterating through the objects of the list, comparing the user's name to the candidateObject.getName(), and if found, returning the index of that object. Am I wrong in assuming that?

Comment: @PrOjEkTeD : Exbury showed you how to iterate through the list, and it is probably the thing to do to remove a node. I added that as an answer, because you (incorrectly as  khelwood and exbury said) used `indexOf` at removal and also to control if a name was already in use. If you implement equals (and hashcode) as I showed above you will be able to use contains or indexOf on the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove using candidate name. `String` is also an `object`. So you are comparing `String` `object` with `Candidate` `object` if you used generic Linked List it will throw a compile time error so use generic linked list

```
LinkedList<Candidate> candidateList = new LinkedList<Candidate>();
```

use iterator to remove object.

```
for(Iterator<Candidate> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Candidate data = iter.next();
    if (data.name.equalIgnoreCase(nameOfCandidate) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: So this what I did:case 3:
    if(candidates < 1)
    {
     System.out.println("\nNo candidates to delete\n");
     break;
    }
    System.out.println("\nEnter name of candidate to delete: ");
    nameOfCandidate = EasyIn.getString();
    for(Iterator<Candidate> iter = candidateList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) 
    {
        Candidate data = iter.next();
        if (data.getCandidateName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameOfCandidate)) 
        {
            iter.remove();
            candidates--;
        }
        else
        {
         System.out.println("Candidate not found");
        }
    }

Comment: Oh man I'm sorry I didn't realize this will come out like this, but anyway, it is still giving me candidate not found

Comment: you are correct but candidateList.indexOf(nameOfCandidate) it will always return -1

Comment: Yes indeed, I understand that now, I'm comparing a String to an object

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, @Exbury I used your method and it works perfectly

```
case 3:
            if(candidates < 1)
            {
                System.out.println("\nNo candidates to delete\n");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("\nEnter name of candidate to delete: ");
            nameOfCandidate = EasyIn.getString();
            Candidate cToDelete = new Candidate(nameOfCandidate, "anyPartyName");
            int candidateIndex =candidateList.indexOf(cToDelete);
            if(candidateIndex == -1)
            {
                System.out.println("\nCandidate can not be found in list\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                candidateList.remove(candidateIndex);
                candidates--;
            }
```